# Problem with Regex in .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to write a a regex to validate a string to match the following rules.

- Must start with a-z (case insensitive)
- Must only contain a-z A-Z 0-9 . -

I've put something together based on my limited knowledge and ran it through an online testing tool for a whole bunch of situations and the results were as I had hoped however when I place the pattern into my .NET code it doesn't match correctly.

The pattern I am using is,

[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\-]*

Is this the correct pattern or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Some examples of what I'm expecting.

- craig.bovis - VALID
- 24craig - INVALID
- craig@bovis - INVALID
- craig24 - VALID
- -craig24 - INVALID
- craig24.bovis-test - VALID

Comment: Don't forget to start your RegEx with ^ to signify the start of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. You need to anchor the match to the beginning and end of the string:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\-]*$
```

The `^` mean "beginning of string" and `$` means "end of string". Without them, the expression will match anywhere *within* the string as well.